Can I set partition key with path(/user/firstName) in Azure Cosmos DB
I have JSON like below
{
  "user": {
    "firstName": "FirstName"
  },
  "attr1": "abcd",
  "attr2": "efgh"
}

I want to use firstName as Partition Key for my Cosmos container. I created my container with partition key as "/user/firstName".
But I am getting Cosmos not found exception when I read with this partition key.
Below is the code I am using to read:
var firstName = "FirstName"
User user= await _container.ReadItemAsync<User>(firstName, new PartitionKey(firstName));


What's the id attribute in your document?

firstName we are using as id. So want to use it as partition key.

My question here is can we use partition key as "/user/firstName"? or do I need to move my firstName property to root?

You can certainly use /user/firstName as partition key.

However, I think you would need to have an id attribute in your JSON.

Not sure if you were just using that as a synthetic example of a nested property but if not firstName certainly doesn't seem a great candidate for partition key


In Azure Cosmos DB, when you use the ReadItemAsync method, it is mandatory to provide both the id and the partition key, you have mentioned only partition key that may be the reason to get the "NotFound" exception as shown above. To resolve the error add id property to to your code, an unique id will generate for each item while creating it as shown below:
{
    "user": {
        "firstName": "FirstName"
    },
    "attr1": "abcd",
    "attr2": "efgh",
    "id": "****",
    "_rid": "****",
    "_self": "*****",
    "_etag": "*****"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": ****
}

Use the unique id value in you code as below:
var id = "<id>"; 
var firstName = "FirstName"; 
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey(firstName); 
try  
{  
    User user = await container.ReadItemAsync<User>(id, partitionKey);  
    Console.WriteLine($"User found: {user.user.firstName}");
}

Then you will be able run the code successfully without any error as shown below:

Here is the complete code for your reference:
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
class Program
{
    private static readonly string EndpointUri = "<cosmosURI>";
    private static readonly string PrimaryKey = <primaryKey>"; 
    private static CosmosClient cosmosClient;
    private static Container container;
 
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, PrimaryKey);
        container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("db", "c1");
 
        // Use the correct id of the item you want to read
        var id = "<id>"; 
        var firstName = "FirstName"; 
        PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey(firstName);  
        try
        {
            User user = await container.ReadItemAsync<User>(id, partitionKey);
            Console.WriteLine($"User found: {user.user.firstName}");       
        }
        catch (CosmosException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Cosmos DB Exception: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Status Code: {ex.StatusCode}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
} 


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

If the answer is "you're missing ID in your call," then that should be a comment and the question should be closed as typo/can't reproduce. It's just a single parameter passed incorrectly.
